# Determine the unknown angle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

[image]

For this question I'm a bit confused and don't know where to start by solving it, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you find the angle at the very top of the figure?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have you learnt about the $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions yet?

Comment: The trick is to use the fact that all angles in a triangle sum up to 180°.

Comment: Yes, but this question (referring to the diagram) is different from ones I've answered so I'm kind of confused as to where I have to start.

Comment: Notice, in right triangle having perpendicular $5$ & hypotenuse $8$, hence $$\sin\theta=\frac{5}{8}\implies \theta=\sin^{-1}\frac{5}{8}=38.68^\circ$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! Will I have to find the altitude length in between the two triangles to find θ?

Comment: @Atoosa You dont't need to calculate anything else but $5/8$.

Comment: So do I just do 90 - 38.68 to find angle θ?

Answer (score 1):

First argue that all three rectangular triangles in the picture are similar. This means that the angle $\theta$ occurs in several places.

Then use trigonometry to define $\theta$ in terms of the sides of a convenient rectangular triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Hypotenuse $ = \dfrac{8^2}{5} = 12.8 $

$$ \sin \theta = \frac{8}{12.8}. $$